# Including non-form in a Django SessionWizardView

Tags: django, django-forms

Can a non-form web page be included in a django SessionWizardView?

For example, I want the user to FillOut Form1, Form2, Then View a web page (in same session) (click next), and then Form3?   All this while maintaining the same session.

If so, how is this best accomplished?  Any examples or snippets?

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly easy hack for this.  Create a plain old form that has one field that is hidden from the user, has no content, and isn't required.

I do this:

```
class BlankForm(forms.Form):
    nothing     = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=HiddenInput)
```

Include it in your SessionWizardView call just like the other pages:

```
SessionWizardView.as_view([Form1, Form2, BlankForm, Form3])
```

In the template page you can use some logic like this to display info:

```
{% if wizard.steps.current == '2' %}
    Whatever you want to show on the BlankForm
{% endif %}
```