# Returning a variable inside a SessionWizardView

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to return a variable to a particular page inside a `SessionWizardView` but not having much luck. My aim is to show users a random image by making its filename the variable and the final part of the `<image src=` attribute.

The problem is that that the below `image()` funcation does not "send" the `display_image` variable to the `SessionWizardView` wizard_form.html page.

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormF(forms.Form):

    def image(request):           
        path_one_images = ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg']

        display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)       
        return render(request, 'wizard_form.html', {'display_image': display_image})    

nothing = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

**wizard_form.html**

To reduce space I am only including the relevant parts of wizard_form.html. I have a small bit of logic [taken from this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237794/1214163) at `{% if wizard.steps.current == '5' %}` which shows the user the below HTML content on the 5th page of the SessionWizzardView.

```
<p>Page: {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{ wizard.management_form }}
                    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                            {{ form }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ wizard.form }}
                {% endif %}
            </table>

        {% if wizard.steps.current == '5' %}

                <h1>Experiment</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

                {% load staticfiles %}                                                              

                    <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}"{{display_image}}/> 

                    <section>   
                        <span class="tooltip"></span>   
                        <div id="slider"></div>  
                        <span class="volume"></span>  
                    </section>      
        {% endif %}
```

Of course the wizard_form.html page is buried in the project at `templates/formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html` ([Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#creating-templates-for-the-forms)) but I believe its more of an issue with the SWV rather than the location of the html file.

Any help is as always, much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown any code that calls the `image` method, so I don't see how it can 'send' the `display_image` variable to the page.

If you want to add a variable to the template context, I suggest you try overriding the [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#advanced-wizardview-methods) method.